# nginx: access_log both compressed and uncompressed

Tags: nginx, logging, gzip

In my "vhost" declaration I have:

```
access_log /WEBSITE_DIR/logs/access.log.gz combined gzip;
```

Problem is I get 2 files, an access.log.gz and an access.log
Why? I want just the .log.gz one..

Comment: Look at the rest of your configuration.

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=cnQBweiR